# Comparing two pandas dataframe cells, and if equal ==, copy other content over - results in error

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing excel files with products and product specific data. They look like this:

dfA

```
EAN Code    Product Name    Color    Price
12345       AAA             xxx      9
45678       BBB             zzz      10
```

and
dfB

```
EAN Code    Product Name    New Price
12-345      AAA             10
45-678      BBB             11
```

I am importing these as always:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame (dfA, columns=["Season", "EAN Code", "Product Name", "..."] , dtype=str)
```

And I am merging them, since there are multiple different excel files:

```
dfA = pd.concat([dfA1, dfA2, dfA3, dfA4, dfA5, dfA6, dfA7, dfA8, dfA9, dfA10, dfA11], ignore_index=False)
```

Then I am deleting the hyphen in the EAN column, because in excel file b there is an unnecessary hyphen in the EAN number.

```
for col in dfB.columns:
   dfB["EAN"] = dfB["EAN"].str.replace('-', '')
```

So far, so good.

Now I try to search through the EAN code column of dfA and search for the same product in dfB. When there is a match, I want to copy over the new price.
This worked great in my old code, although it took about 15 minutes for the script to search through a half million rows...
This worked quite well in the past, but now I am trying to achieve the same, but I get an error message. This is my simplified code:

```
for i in dfA.index:
   for j in dfB.index:
      if dfA.loc[i, "EAN"] == dfB.loc[j, "EAN"]:
         print ("EAN", number,"times found!")
         number=number+1
         dfA.loc[i, "Price"] = dfB.loc[j, "New Price"]
```

The print statement is only a feedback for me, so that I see wether the script is still doing something.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:...", line 72, in <module>
    if dfA.loc[i, "EAN"] == dfB.loc[j, "EAN"]:
  File "C:...", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Why am I getting this now?

Comment: You can do `dfB["EAN"] = dfB["EAN"].str.replace('-', '')` only once, btw. No need to do that in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), after setting up a common EAN Code:

```
out = dfA.merge(
          dfB.assign(**{'EAN Code': dfB['EAN Code'].str.replace('-', '')
                                    .astype(int) # only if dfA has an int
                     }),
          on='EAN Code')
```

output:

```
   EAN Code Product Name_x Color  Price Product Name_y  New Price
0     12345            AAA   xxx      9            AAA         10
1     45678            BBB   zzz     10            BBB         11
```

Comment: Maybe that could work. But I would have to delete and rearrange the columns afterwards. But I would like to understand why this approach worked last time, and now it does not. Why am I getting a Series now?

Comment: I don't know why it worked and not anymore, but for sure you shouldn't use it. It is easy and fast to add/remove columns, much slower to loop over all combinations. A merge of 500k rows should be done in tens of milliseconds, or seconds if this is a tricky merge.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to test a condition somewhere, it's obviously in the `if`-part: `if dfA.loc[i, "EAN"] == dfB.loc[j, "EAN"]`.

`dfA.loc[i, "EAN"]` happens to be a Series sometimes and/or `dfB.loc[j, "EAN"]` too.

So the result of `... == ...` is a Series, but `if` expects a boolean. You need to reduce this Series to a boolean using the appropriate method (they propose `empty`, `bool()`, `any()`, etc.)

I assume that you expect `dfA.loc[i, "EAN"]` to give you a scalar and not a Series but it's not always the case (idem for `dfB.loc[j, "EAN"]`). **So check your data. How are your `i` and `j`s?**

---

###### Remark

I recommend you to use `df.at[i, col]` rather than `df.loc[i, col]`, when you know that you should get a scalar. It's faster and will send errors if you can't get a scalar, so it will be easier to debug.

Comment: "dfA.loc[i, "EAN"] happens to be a Series sometimes and/or dfB.loc[j, "EAN"] too." But why? Why is the result a series now? Last time I did something like this in the same way, and it worked. And how can I check my data?

Comment: I don't know why. Your data are not as expected, that's what we can say at least. It's a series because `i` is a list-like structure and not a scalar (string or int in your case). Then `loc` returns a Series.You can catch the `ValueError` and put a breakpoint in the `except` clause to inspect `i` and `j` for instance.